# JQuery to disable button not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have the following button:

```
<a type="button" class="btn btn-primary disabledButton">Download</a>
```

I want to disable it using the `.prop` property of JQuery. Like this:

```
$('.disabledButton').prop('disabled', true);
```

However, it is not working as nothing changed. Any ideas?

Comment: If you're looking for a workaround without using a button, what are you trying to do exactly? Like what functionality are you trying to change by disabling the button?

Comment: This is not a button, it's a link (anchor tag).

Comment: updated answer for anchor workaround

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason it is not working is because it's a hyper link and it does not have the `disabled` property. Only thing you can do is `preventDefault`

https://dev.w3.org/html5/html-author/#the-a-element

```
<a type="button" class="btn btn-primary disabledButton">Download</a>

$('a.disabledButton').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Has to be a button not an anchor

```
<button class="btn btn-primary disabledButton">Download</button>
```

Now this should work

```
$('.disabledButton').prop('disabled', true);
```

**UPDATED as OP mentioned he has to use an anchor**

Workaround one:

```
$('.disabledButton').css('pointer-events', 'none');
```

Workaround two: (Prevent default)

```
 $('.disabledButton').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: He has to use an anchor.

Comment: Thank you, answer edited